# Cors Policy Error when trying to connect to API using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am getting a cors policy error when trying to connect my React WEB application to my Node.js server, they have different endpoints.

I tried using CORS (a node.js package) for providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS, as showing bellow:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

var corsOptions = {
  origin:
    'https://idcapex-web-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({
    msg:
      'This is CORS-enabled for only https://idcapex-web-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com.'
  })
})

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.json())
```

I tested CORS by using cURL too, and this was my response:

```
$ curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Origin: http://localhost" --head https://idcapex-api-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   119    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: https://idcapex-web-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com
vary: Origin
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 119
etag: W/"77-AdhBn2OLZD9G030p12/wnx/v9oI"
date: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 22:58:58 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=5
set-cookie: 3445b7ee597b15dbb7cad24a97e79d23=e41350b2903f2a39c85294550a7c8e19; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
cache-control: private
```

I dont know why it does not work, it seems everything is ok but i keep getting the error in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://idcapex-api-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com/api/table' from origin 'https://idcapex-web-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://idcapex-api-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com/api/users/create' from origin 'https://idcapex-web-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Is both the server and client on the same host? If so you could probably just send the request as a relative path, as in fetch('/api/whatever') instead of doing the entire fully formed path.

Comment: It doesn't look like the cors middleware will see the OPTIONS preflight request

Comment: Server and client are not in the same host, they got different endpoints aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, related to CORS my code is okay. I wasn't root admin of the MongoDB Database, so i coudnt do any operations, changed that and everything was fine after.

Answer (score 0):

error says no Access-Control-Allow-Origin, i  think you should add this header when sending the request

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
```

The above is the syntax

Comment: I tried, using axios request as below:

const api = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    baseURL: 'https://idcapex-api-suprimentos-dev.apps.rosa-gerdau.bxnu.p1.openshiftapps.com/api/'
})

But i got the same errors:

https://ik.imagekit.io/fx09rzyx3a4/Capturar_B-rKzhLqsMB.PNG

Answer (score 0):

```
const corsOptions = {
   origin: 'URL', 
   methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
   credentials: true,
   allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type']
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

try to include methods

Comment: I tried, it didn't work, same errors: 
ik.imagekit.io/fx09rzyx3a4/Capturar_B-rKzhLqsMB.PNG